# Installing MySQLdb for Python on OSX 10.6 - Error Creating .egg

Tags: python, mysql

Running Python 2.7 X86 on Snow Leopard. Installed 64 bit MySQL to avoid conflicts between bit versions. However, still have issues installing MySQLdb.

After following [this](http://learninglamp.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/mysqldb-python-mysql-and-os-x-a-match-made-in-satans-bum/) and various other online guides I'm still no closer. The output I receive during install is:

```
$ ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
copying build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-    10.6-x86_64/egg' to it
error: dist/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg: Permission denied
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that at one point you tried running `python setup.py` under `sudo` and now have a `dist` directory belonging to root.  Clear out the existing `dist` subdirectory in your build directory and rerun:

```
sudo rm -rf ./dist
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install
```

If you then get permission errors in the final install step, you may need to run the `install` step under `sudo`:

```
sudo bash
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
/path/to/same/python2.7 setup.py install
exit
```

but it's probably better to not do that if you don't have to.

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted - that's the way things work at StackOverflow!